# Build Android Using Gradle

Tags: android

I am still getting the error

"A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

Gradle version 1.10 is required. Current version is 1.12. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in D:\AndroidStudioWorkspace\HelloGradl e\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-1.10-all.zip"

Though I updated my build.gradle as follows:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it by creating a fresh workspace and creating a new project in it.

Then do File>Export>Generate Gradle build files.

Once the build.gradle file is generated as follows:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

Go to command prompt, go to the project directory and run the command:
gradle build

Thats it! U will see the following output:

```
:preBuild
:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild
:checkDebugManifest
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:dexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:validateDebugSigning
:packageDebug UP-TO-DATE
:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:preReleaseBuild
:checkReleaseManifest
:prepareReleaseDependencies
:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:compileReleaseJava UP-TO-DATE
:lintVitalRelease SKIPPED
:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:preDexRelease UP-TO-DATE
:dexRelease UP-TO-DATE
:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:packageRelease UP-TO-DATE
:assembleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:compileLint
:lint
Ran lint on variant debug: 0 issues found
Ran lint on variant release: 0 issues found
Wrote HTML report to file:/D:/GradleWorkspace2/HelloWorld/build/lint-results.htm
l
Wrote XML report to D:\GradleWorkspace2\HelloWorld\build\lint-results.xml
:check
:build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 16.323 secs
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the following file: `project_root/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`.

Make sure the `distributionUrl` is set to `1.10`:

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip
```

Comment: Yes it is set as follows:
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip